# Validating Yup files uploads with typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-hook-form, react-typescript, yup

I'm using yup and react-hook-form in typescript.
And in my code I do this:

```
const schema: yup.ObjectSchema<IUserEdit> = yup.object().shape({
    file: yup.mixed(),
    username: yup.string().max(255),
  });
```

My IUserEdit:

```
export interface IUserEdit {
    username: string,
    file: FileList

}
```

And typescript complains about the type mismatch, I don't understand how to fix it.

```
Type 'ObjectSchema<{ file: any; username: string | undefined; }, AnyObject, { file: undefined; username: undefined; }, "">' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchema<IUserEdit, AnyObject, any, "">'.
  The types of 'default(...).fields.username' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<string, AnyObject, any, any>'.
      Type 'ISchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<string, AnyObject, any, any>'.
        Type 'ISchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, any, ......
```

I found the similar question [How to validate Yup files uploads with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327678/how-to-validate-yup-files-uploads-with-typescript) but the solution doesn't help me